# The Podfile for Hyperledger Indy seems to be linking to the wrong repository

Tags: ios, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

Trying to intall Hyperledger Indy using the documentation provided.

When I attempt to install it I get the message

```
[!] Error installing libindy-objc
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/fy/jxn6l3m16938_yg6gldn1c9w0000gn/T/d20191009-64232-45n38a/file.zip https://repo.sovrin.org/ios/libindy/stable/indy-objc/1.10.0/libindy-objc.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

If I got that the URL there is no file... If I update my pod with...

source 'https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk.git'

```
target 'Koncordant' do
  pod 'libindy'
  pod 'libindy-objc' , '~> 1.8.2'
end
```

It will install

Answer (score 1):

1. Right below '#platform' line in Podfile, copy paste below code.

   ```
   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
   source 'https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk.git'
   ```
2. Inside 'target' below 'use_frameworks!', copy paste below code.

   ```
   pod 'libindy'
   pod 'libindy-objc', '~> 1.8.2'
   ```
3. Run 'pod install' from terminal in project's path.
4. Open '.xcworkspace', not  '.xcodeproj'.
5. Add a swift file in xcode. Xcode will automatically prompt for 'Bridging 
   Header', add it
   (If your base proj is in swift, then add an obj-c file.I dont know the reason behind this step, but it gives runtime error otherwise).
6. Import wallet header in your files where you want to call Indy API's.

   ```
   #import <Indy/Indy.h>
   ```
7. Call Indy methods.

   ```
   [[IndyWallet sharedInstance] createWallet...];
   ```